# Cannot convert date from Jan 11, 2002 to 2002-01-11 in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I'm trying to change the date format in R.
I have a data frame and one of the columns contains dates (as strings) in given format:
Jan 11, 2002
but I would like to change the format to (also as string):
2002-01-11

I have tried many things, but nothing seems to work.
My best shot was trying to convert it to Data object and then convert it back to string, but in different format.

Here is a piece of my code:
`df$date = strftime(as.Date(df$date, format="%b %d, %Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")`

I was trying other ways, but the result is always NA or a string, but in 'old' format.

I think there is something wrong with the first format: "%b %d, %Y", because when I tried the same thing but with different input, e.g. 11/01/2002 ("%d/%m/%Y") everything worked just fine.

I'm pretty new to R so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't this: `strftime(as.Date('Jan 11, 2002', format="%b %d, %Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")` give you what you want? Besides you need to convert to date format first in order to be able to reformat it

Comment: The use of `%b` depends on your locale on your computer. Set `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")` to reflect North-American usage and run your code again.

Answer (score 1):

This would need a reproducible example for an accurate response.

First, confirm that the source dates are all in the same format, otherwise, this can lead to parsing errors.

Try the following:

```
# Using Lubridate: lubridate::mdy (note, this can be any order depending on your data, e.g. mdy, dmy, ymd, etc. so is flexible
df <- df %>% mutate(strftime = lubridate::mdy(strftime))
```

Please do look into reproducible examples to get the best answers.

Comment: @DarrenTsai  For the lubridate option use:  `lubridate::mdy("Jan 11, 2002")` You are right on the as.Date(), I don't use the function, so was too quick. I will edit my comment. Try the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of packages that can help (as well as base R functions, see the first comment).  Here is my favourite solution *which does require any input format help*:

```
> library(anytime)      # for function anydate()
> input <- "Jan 11, 2002"
> d <- anydate(input)
> d
[1] "2002-01-11"
>
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip. This is a great function as it can parse different formats in the same vector. Any thoughts when we think about different formats? e.g. for December 1, 2022: ```anytime::anydate(c("2022-12-01", "2022-01-12", "12-01-22", "01-12-2022", "12-01-2022"))``` This throws an error if you don't use a four digit year, and depending on the order, can mistake the date for January 12, 2022. I'd like this to work, so appreciate if I'm missing something (and perhaps some of the dates I put in may never or rarely occur).

Comment: @glenn_in_boston From `?anytime`: *"A number of fixed formats are tried in succession. These include the standard ISO format ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS’ as well as different local variants including several forms popular in the United States. Two-digits years and clearly ambiguous formats such as ‘03/04/05’ are ignored. In the case of parsing failure a NA value is returned."*

Comment: See the documentation of the package, Some format are ambigious, generally discouraged -- yet widely used so we aspire to walk a fine line and rely a little bit of common separation characters to distinguish between the (sane) standard ISO or European format or the (insame, frankly, but common) North American format.

Comment: Spot on @DarrenTsai and thank you -- we typed that at the same time.

Comment: Thanks both. Much appreciated. I figured it was hierarchical. I often end up with dates from a mix of Europe (dmy) and the US (mdy), where this would potentially misread certain dates. (either of the last two options in my example)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you wrote it wrong, see, you've written:

```
df$date = strftime(as.Date(df$date, format="%b %d, %Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

should be:

```
df$date = strftime(as.Date(df$date, format="%m %d, %Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

in format() there's a '%b' and I think it should be '%m'

Comment: `%b` means the abbreviated month name. See [?strptime](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime)